Adding modifier to the text inside of TextField in Jetpack Compose
I want to add modifier to the text inside of textfield.
TextField(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.White)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .testTag(ADD_EDIT_TITLE_TAG)
        .sharedBounds(
            sharedContentState = rememberSharedContentState(key = "title/$noteId"),
            animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
            boundsTransform = { _, _ ->
                tween(durationMillis = 5000)
            }
        ),
    singleLine = true,
    placeholder = {
        Text(
            text = "Title",
            color = Color.LightGray,
            fontSize = pickedTitleFontSize.sp
        )
    },
    visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None + {

    },
    value = titleTf,
    onValueChange = { titleTf = it },
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
        unfocusedContainerColor = Color(pickedBackgroundColor),
        focusedContainerColor = Color(pickedBackgroundColor),
        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
        cursorColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
        selectionColors = TextSelectionColors(
            handleColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
            backgroundColor = colorResource(
                id = R.color.orange
            )
        )
    ),
    textStyle = TextStyle(
        fontWeight = if (titleIsBold) FontWeight.Bold else FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = pickedTitleFontSize.sp,
        color = Color(pickedTitleColor),
        fontStyle = if (titleIsItalic) FontStyle.Italic else FontStyle.Normal,
        textDecoration = if (titleIsUnderline) TextDecoration.Underline else if (titleIsLineThrough) TextDecoration.LineThrough else TextDecoration.None
    ),
)

I can only add a modifier to the textfield itself. Is there any way to apply it also on the text inside?
I want to try new Shared Elements between composables. I have a text and when I click on it another composable appears, and that text is shared to that composable.
